# GWT Datepicker set default date when opened

Tags: gwt, datepicker

GWT 2.7 :
I am using gwt date picker and my code is something like this

```
DatePicker datePickerW = new DatePicker();
datePickerW.setYearArrowsVisible( true );
Date date = new Date();
CalendarUtil.addMonthsToDate( date, 2 );
datePickerW.setVisible( true );
```

Now when the page refreshes and date picker is opened datepicker should initially display current date + two months. Like today is 28 aug then date highlighted should be 28 oct.

It does not displays highlighted date other than today's date. Is there any way to display highlighted date as we want? I can use any GWT alternate to datepicker as well. DateBox is not an option though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if we setCurrentMonth() first. So the following code works

```
DatePicker datePickerW = new DatePicker();
datePickerW.setYearArrowsVisible( true );
Date date = new Date();
CalendarUtil.addMonthsToDate( date, 2 );
datePickerW.setCurrentMonth(date);
datePickerW.setValue(date);
datePickerW.setVisible( true );
```